# Why Kotlin does not allow slash in identifiers

Tags: scala, unicode, kotlin

The Unicode is allowed in identifiers in backticks

```
val `id` = "1"
```

But slash is not allowed

```
val `application/json` = "application/json"
```

In Scala we can have such names.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a JVM limitation. From the specification section [4.2.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.2.2):

> Names of methods, fields, local variables, and formal parameters are stored as unqualified names. An unqualified name must contain at least one Unicode code point and must not contain any of the ASCII characters . ; [ / (that is, period or semicolon or left square bracket or forward slash).

In Scala names are mangled to avoid this limitation, in Kotlin they are not.

Comment: I'll add that that the reason Scala needs such mangling is because there operators like `/`, `+`, etc. are treated as normal method names.

Answer (score 9):

Kotlin's identifiers are used as-is, without any mangling, in the names of JVM classes and methods generated from the Kotlin code. The slash has a special meaning in JVM names (it separates packages and class names). Therefore, Kotlin doesn't allow using it in an identifier.

Comment: Well, somehow in Scala this is not a problem.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what Scala does.

Comment: From Todd's answer: "In Scala names are mangled to avoid this limitation, in Kotlin they are not."

Comment: FYI here's how Scala handles name mangling: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/reflect/NameTransformer.scala . As you can see, `/` symbol is translated to `$div`